# AWS Cognito /aws-amplify errors - crypto undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create a vuejs wrapper for aws cognito and am having trouble with their API. The documentation is poor, but what I have is giving me a `"Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined` in the console.

Set up to configure amplify

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { CognitoUser } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

Amplify.configure({
      Auth: {
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: config.IdentityPoolId,
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: config.Region,
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: config.UserPoolId,
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: config.ClientId,
        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: false,
      }
    });
```

and this is all the code thats run on initialization to cause errors. what am i doing wrong? I just want to be able to access `Auth` to call methods on it.

For clarity, I'm exporting a function to register the vuex module and the below code (aside from imports) is inside the init action.

```
export default (store, config, namespace = 'cognito') => {
  store.registerModule(namespace, {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
  })
  store.dispatch(`${namespace}/init`, config)
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior, but I'm curious: why is `amazon-cognito-identity-js` being imported?  I have projects that use it, and projects that use `aws-amplify`, but no projects that use both.  Can you lose the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` import and verify you still have the same issue?

Comment: @MikePatrick hmm, interesting. The docs are a bit unclear on how to use this API so I ended up thinking I needed them both. I will try that and report back.